# Elixir - why is there no compiler warning for these duplicate headers?

Tags: elixir, compiler-warnings

Today while walking through some code I came across the following two function headers and realized that, as far as I can tell, they should be duplicates. Same number of parameters and no matches or guards to let us bypass the first one. But the compiler isn't giving me a warning that the second will never match. Any explanation why that would be?

```
  def update_display_cache(context, text, line_no, position, text, adjusted_text, _) do
  def update_display_cache(context, display_line, line_no, position, text, adjusted_text, _) do
```

I made a couple of simple functions with matching parameter lists, including one with the trailing _ parameter and they all gave the expected warning.
`warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 24 always matches`

I also copied and pasted the entire first function header and body without changes and still didn't get a warning.

Elixir 1.7.4

Comment: Just to be sure... is the function defined in the same module?
And are you sure that things recompiled?  (Sometimes removing the _build directory is the ultimate check)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can see both functions have the same number of parameters with no guards helping to distinguish between them.

Comment: The history of this apparently goes back several years through several modules, copied and pasted. Trust me, it's been recompiled! @GuruStron that is the point of the question. I see no difference between the headers except a name, so why doesn't the compiler warn me?

Comment: @Sinc Yep, missed the "no" in question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The param `text` appears two times in the first definition, adding the extra constraint that those two values have to be equal to match.

A simpler minimal example reproducing it:

```
  def equals?(a, a), do: true
  def equals?(_, _), do: false
```

Comment: ️ Sharp eye! ️

Comment: Haha thx, it actually took me some time to notice ;)

Comment: Thanks @sabiwara, now I can get back to my real job and stop staring!

Comment: I'm fairly new to Elixir and forgot the third way that a function header can be constrained: matches, guards, and reused variable names. Then again, my team lead who has been doing Elixir for several years and wrote the original code didn't spot why they weren't duplicates.